# DataContext.SetSaveStream issue

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am adding a file to a list item using datacontext's setsavestream method but I am getting the following error (the attached file is image/jpg type)

Error: The content type 'image/bmp' is not supported.

I am using listdata.svc for this.

Thanks.